# Set headers - capybara mechanize or selenium

Tags: selenium, http-headers, cucumber, mechanize, capybara

In my cucumbers, I need to add a key/value pair to the http headers when I request a page with capybara using the mechanize driver or perhaps the selenium driver.

I'm using capybara 1.1.1 and mechanize 2.0.1 and selenium 2.5.0

But how?

Here are my step definitions:

```
When /^set some headers$/ do
  #set some headers here
  visit('/url')
end

Then /^some result$/ do
  #check page responds to header
end
```

Many thanks,
Rim

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Mechanize you should be able to set headers in the request like this:

```
When /^set some headers$/ do
    #set some headers here
    page.driver.agent.request_headers = {"X-Header" => "value"}
    visit('/url')
end
```